# about lispbox. how to run .lisp file by using it?

Tags: lisp

I download lispbox for lisp IDE on Mac OS.
I can run lisp command in lispbox at interactive mode.
My question is how can I run .lisp code by using it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Common Lisp load function in interactive mode: `(load "pathname.lisp")`

Alternatively, see if you can use the shortcut `Ctrl-c Ctrl-l` in the editor to load the Lisp file.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can run files via command line using Emacs Lisp or Clozure CL, included in LispBox.

I'm using LispBox 0.7 on Windows 7, 64 bits. The commands are:

`emacs-23.2\bin\emacs.exe --script hello.lisp`

or
`ccl-1.6-windowsx86\wx86cl64.exe --load hello.lisp`

The second command needs `(quit)` at the end of the program, though.